# Button type="button" still refreshing page and not enabling modal to load

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I read through some stackoverflow questions and saw that changing a button type to `button` enables the modal to load instead of refreshing the page, however I am still getting the page refresh behaviour with the following html structure:

**.html**

```
<div class="shop-item-overlay">
    <button type="button" class="quickview" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">{{context.quickView}}</button>
    <button type="button" class="heart">
      <span class="sr-only">{{context.wishlist}}</span>
    </button>
  </div>
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Quickview</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

There is no external css or js acting upon these classes. The modal button is `type="button"`, any ideas where the problem might be?

Comment: Instead of using button please use the `<a>`

Comment: All else being equal, yes. buttons with a type of "submit" will submit while buttons with type="button" won't. In this case, that probably means the framework performs a submit!